# Multiple threaded in vb.net to divide the work of huge for loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, loops

I am new the multiple threaded in vb.net but I would like to how to construct the following program

- I want to loop from 1 to 4096766 inside each time I want to query remote server to get one value
  the problem that each value takes 10 seconds to be returned, however the whole cost is because of network issue and not related to my loop.
- I want to divide the loop into 1000 separate loops for example, the first loop 
  from 1 to 1000 and the second from 10001 to 2000 and so on then I will execute the 1000 threads concurrently to speed up the process

**Note:** many numbers will return nothing but the problem is in the time out when the number has no related name the time out is 10 seconds which is very costly

**first thread**

```
open text file (filename = 1000.txt)
for i = 1 to 1000 
    getEmpName(i)
    write i to text file
    write name to text file
    new line
next
```

**Second thread**

```
open text file (filename = 2000.txt)
for i = 10001 to 2000 
    getEmpName(i)
    write i to text file
    write name to text file
    new line
next
```

this will save my life if doable
thanks for support

Comment: You want to sent 4096766 requests to a remote server? I don't think that is advisable. Is the server in your power? Then you should change the interface the server exposes...

Comment: Each new thread reserves 1Mb of memory, so opening 10,000 threads concurrently is not wise unless you are running on Deep Blue or something

Comment: ok then at least 1000 threads I can run the program for a week, yes the server is under my control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multithreading this work requires your `getEmpName(i)` sub to be threadsafe, that is it should be careful when using other ressources, library calls and variables (like storing the EmpName for i...).

If your current implementation works right now, split the files and launch your program multiple times, all you need to do is collect the outputs and maybe combine them. This is a quick and safe way to "multithread" / "multiprocess" ; )

For Real Multithrad, have your normal workflow read the file, Launch a new Thread from the [Threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx) for each i and wait for the calls to return your names, maybe write all names to a thrad-safe list or collection, sort and output. Watch the maximum number of concurrent network connections and errors.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a far better idea to create a look-up in such a way that getEmpName(i) does not require a timeout to indicate a name couldn't be found.

If it can't be reduced from within the getEmpName(i) function itself, it may be a good idea to cache the results of a first run and refresh the cache on a semi-regular basis (dependent on how often the data changes).

That way, when looking up a name, you hit the cache, and can quickly discover if the name exists or not (next to 0 cost).